# Next and previous to img slider

Tags: wordpress

I want a free wordpress plugin to show images with next and previous button
I am using img-show-box plugin but this plugin doesn't have next and previous button..

Comment: this isn't a programming question, you should try this at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> You can Use easing slider  [wordpress easing slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easing-slider/)
>
> then you have to enable next and previous button from admin panel.